# como hacer en el contador de una notificacion cuando pase de 20 salga 20+

Tags: php, php7, notificaciones

buenas  nohes como indique en el enunciado tengo un contador que cada vez que tenga un registro  efectivamente sale la cantida deseada pero si tengo **200 registro** el numero en la notificacion sera **200** quiero mostrar en ves de **X** cantidad de registro que salga 10+ ... 20+ o 30++

```
$coint = $bd->query("SELECT * from solicitudes WHERE notificacion = '0'");
$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($coint);



?>

<?php
 
      if ($rows['solicitudes_id'] >= 1  ) {
      
echo "<div class='mostrar'>".$result->num_rows."</div>";
}else{


}
```

Answer (score 0):

¿No te sirve una estructura `if-else` estándar?

```
$numr = $result->num_rows;

if($numr < 10) {
    $res = $numr;
} elseif($numr < 20) {
    $res = '10+';
} elseif($numr < 30) {
    $res = '20+';
} else {
    $res = '30++';
}
```

El bloque `if-else` se puede escribir en una línea usando [operador ternario](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). Como son varias comparaciones, resulta menos legible, pero es lo mismo:

```
$res = ($numr<10) ? $numr : (($numr<20) ? '10+' : (($numr<30) ? '20+' : '30++'));
```

Finalmente incorporas el resultado en el html:

```
echo '<div class="mostrar">'.$res.'</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es mostrar la decena (o centena y decena) y la unidad en cero, puedes dividir por 10, castearlo a entero, multiplicarlo por diez y luego concatenarle '+'.

```
<?php
$cantidadSinUnidades = ((int) ($result->num_rows / 10)) * 10;

echo "<div class='mostrar'>{$cantidadSinUnidades}+</div>";
?>
```

Otra solución es usar la funcion  intdiv(int $dividend, int $divisor): int, dividendo sería la cantidad y el divisor sería 10, luego tendrías multiplicar por diez.

```
<?php
$cantidadSinUnidades = intdiv(result->num_rows, 10) * 10;

echo "<div class='mostrar'>{$cantidadSinUnidades}+</div>";
?>
```

Ten en cuenta que de esta forma, cuando la cantidad sea menor a diez te mostrará: `0+`.